# How to opening a new class within java

Tags: java

Started of with java coding for school. when i create the following code it won't work.
Please help me out.

```
 import javax.swing.*;

 import java.awt.*;

 public class StartScherm extends JFrame
 {

 public static void main( String[] args ){

JFrame frame = new StartScherm();
frame.setSize( 800, 800 );
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
frame.setTitle( "CityTours" );
JPanel Paneel = new Paneel();
frame.setContentPane( Paneel );
frame.setVisible( true );
}
}


class Paneel extends JPanel {

private JButton Eng, LoginAdmin, LoginUser;
private JTextField Text;


public Paneel(){

    setLayout (null);

    Eng = new JButton ("Bring me to the English version");
    Eng.setBounds(250,20,300,20);
    Eng.addActionListener(newEngHandler());

    Text = new JTextField (" Welkom bij CityTours ");
    Text.setBounds(100,80,600,600);
    Text.setEditable (false);

    LoginAdmin = new JButton ("Login administrator");
    LoginAdmin.setBounds(100,720,200,20);

    LoginUser = new JButton ("Login gebruiker");
    LoginUser.setBounds(500,720,200,20);

    add (Eng);
    add (Text);
    add (LoginAdmin);
    add (LoginUser);

}
class EngHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        this.dispose();
        new MainScreen().setVisible(true);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to create a JButton called Eng to close the frame of StartScherm.Java and open a frame of MainScreen.Java (all in the same project)

All it does is create 3 JButtons and a JTextField, and the Eng JButton action won't work. (error: cannot find symbol)

Please help me and explain to me what i do wrong.

Comment: Please, format the code. Your question is too difficult to read.

Comment: **new MainScreen()** what is MainScreen(), I do not see it anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear from your code what is `MainScreen` but, let me give you an idea on how you can switch between two JFrame windows with a button click.

You need access to `isVisible()` and `setVisible()` methods of `JFrame` in order to hide/display a window. Since, I do not know what `MainScreen` is, I will use `StartScherm` and create two instance of it (two windows with different titles) and then switch between the two.

Declare two instances of `StartScherm` outside your main method in `StartScherm` as shown below:

```
public class StartScherm extends JFrame {
    static JFrameCloseEvent frame1; 
    static JFrameCloseEvent frame2; 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
         //your main code initializing frame1 and frame2 goes here 
    }
}
```

The reason we declare `frame1` and `frame2` outside main method is because we want to be able to reference them in `Paneel` class. The reason they are `static` is because we initialize them in main method and main is `static` that is why.

Now that we have to instances of `StartScherm` as frame1 and frame2 we can initialize them differently in main method of `StartScherm`, see below:

```
//already declared frame1 outside main method
frame1 = new JFrameCloseEvent();
frame1.setSize(800, 800);
frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame1.setTitle("CityTours Default Language");
JPanel Paneel = new Paneel();
frame1.setContentPane(Paneel);
//frame1 be visible when program start
frame1.setVisible(true);
```

And we will will initialize the frame2 in a similiar fashion but, with different title and set its visibility to false. See below:

```
frame2 = new JFrameCloseEvent();
frame2.setSize(800, 800);
frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame2.setTitle("CityTours English Version");
JPanel Paneel2 = new Paneel();
frame2.setContentPane(Paneel2);
//set visibility to false because frame1 is visible at beginning
frame2.setVisible(false);
```

Now that we have both `frame1` and `frame2` initialized. We can tweak our `Paneel` to properly implement an `ActionListener` and switch visibility of the frame1 and frame2. In order to set `ActionListener` on a button, I prefer the following approach:

```
Eng = new JButton("Bring me to the English version");
Eng.setBounds(250, 20, 300, 20);
Eng.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(StartScherm.frame1.isVisible()) {
           StartScherm.frame1.setVisible(false);
           StartScherm.frame2.setVisible(true);
        } else {
           StartScherm.frame1.setVisible(true);
           StartScherm.frame2.setVisible(false);
        }
   }
});
```

As you can see above, I attach the `ActionListener` straight to button. Since both `frame1` and `frame2` use `Paneel` hence, they will get the same button with action listener. When the button is clicked, the `actionPerformed` is executed which checks whether `frame1` is visible or `frame2`. If `frame1` is visible then it will set its visibility to false and set visibility of `frame2` to true, else other way round.

Make above changes to your code, that is properly implement ActionListener as shown above, and make sure that your `frame1` and `frame2` instances are accessible in `actionPerformed` method.

I have modified your code to make it runnable, see below (obviously I removed references to MainScreen because,  the only difference between frame1 and frame2 is title).

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class StartScherm extends JFrame {
    static StartScherm frame1; 
    static StartScherm frame2; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        frame1 = new StartScherm();
        frame1.setSize(800, 800);
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setTitle("CityTours Default Language");
        JPanel Paneel = new Paneel();
        frame1.setContentPane(Paneel);
        frame1.setVisible(true);


        frame2 = new StartScherm();
        frame2.setSize(800, 800);
        frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame2.setTitle("CityTours English Version");
        JPanel Paneel2 = new Paneel();
        frame2.setContentPane(Paneel2);
        frame2.setVisible(false);
    }
}

class Paneel extends JPanel {
    private JButton Eng, LoginAdmin, LoginUser;
    private JTextField Text;

    public Paneel() {

        setLayout(null);

        Eng = new JButton("Bring me to the English version");
        Eng.setBounds(250, 20, 300, 20);
        Eng.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               if(StartScherm.frame1.isVisible()) {
                   StartScherm.frame1.setVisible(false);
                   StartScherm.frame2.setVisible(true);
               } else {
                   StartScherm.frame1.setVisible(true);
                   StartScherm.frame2.setVisible(false);
               }
            }
        });

        Text = new JTextField(" Welkom bij CityTours ");
        Text.setBounds(100, 80, 600, 600);
        Text.setEditable(false);

        LoginAdmin = new JButton("Login administrator");
        LoginAdmin.setBounds(100, 720, 200, 20);

        LoginUser = new JButton("Login gebruiker");
        LoginUser.setBounds(500, 720, 200, 20);

        add(Eng);
        add(Text);
        add(LoginAdmin);
        add(LoginUser);

    }
}
```

Comment: @Nigel glad it helped, since you are new to Stackoverflow, I want to remind you that you also have the option to mark an answer as **accepted** if it helped you, see here http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

```
Eng.addActionListener(newEngHandler());
```

should be

```
Eng.addActionListener(new EngHandler());
```

`newEngHandler()` would denote a method which cannot be found `new EngHandler()` would denote instantiating a new class